# Question placement

Tags: discussion, help-suggestion

I’ve seen questions on the math stack exchange get closed since they did not include a math question, but instead a question pertaining to math. For example asking “what type of math is needed to etc. etc.” Where would one ask such a question?

Comment: reddit?  Quora?  someone at your local university or community college?

Comment: It's hard to respond in the abstract.  Have you had such a Question closed?  I'm familiar with (and have answered) some posts that asked "what kind of math is needed..." but based that query on a math problem (or a family of such problems).

Comment: I've seen questions on math.stackexchange get closed even though they did include a math question. Dozens of times. Hundreds. Maybe thousands.

Comment: Try the MSE chatrooms, perhaps. The Mathematics chatroom might be useful. Nevertheless, let me know if you can come with an example of the "etc." that you refer to. To attempt a few ,if you are looking at : "what type of math is needed to study epidemic modelling" or "what type of math is needed to invest in the stock market" then with *enough* refinement , as soft-questions these can very well become on-topic for MSE (and perhaps very informative as well). For the rest, I'd say use chatrooms or contact MSE users who can talk to you offline.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon The recommendation to use the chatrooms is slightly fraught, as one needs to have sufficient reputation to use chat.  The threshold is pretty low (15 XP, I think?), but it is still an obstruction.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I agree and I also forgot to mention the reputation (important since OP doesn't have the reputation to chat), so thanks. The rest of my comments would stay the same.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses that's very helpful!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon The question I have is about the math needed for fluid dynamics. More specifically to what extent I should learn those math topics so that I am able to pretty much learn anything (within reason) in fluid dynamics. If I refine the question by including specific topics I want to learn, would this make a good question in your opinion?

Comment: @JustinH It would! There are two things I need to show you (1) [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluid-dynamics+reference-request) is a list of reference-request questions relating to fluid dynamics on MSE, and may already contain answers to what you wish to ask. If you still wish to ask a question you can certainly reference one of these questions. (2) It's better to be specific rather than general, at least nowadays. For example, if you are tackling a particular problem in fluid dynamics and are using certain books and papers as references, consider citing these.

Comment: (Even if those books lie outside the purview of pure mathematics) Your question looks very much on-topic for MSE as a reference request, unless one of the questions that is part of the list already covers it, in which case it looks like a duplicate. My suggestion : attempt to create a question, and include (1) What your core problem is , as a subset of fluid dynamics (2) What you've been reading so far, mathematics or not (3) Any posts in the list that you think partially but not fully answers your question. Then tagging this as reference-request and fluid-dynamics is great!